# Keras sentiment analysis with LSTM how to test it

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, lstm

I'm trying to do sentiment analysis with Keras on my texts using example [imdb_lstm.py](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/imdb_lstm.py) but I dont know how to test it.
I stored my model and weights into file and it look like this:

```
model = model_from_json(open('my_model_architecture.json').read())
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
          optimizer='adam',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
model.load_weights('my_model_weights.h5')

results = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, batch_size=32)
```

but ofcourse I dont know how should `X_test` and `y_test` look like. Would anyone pls help me?

Comment: you should split your data into training and testing parts, train on one, and test on the other, thats all you need to do

Comment: thx for reply. would you please write me a small example how it should look like? Model is already trained from imdb dataset

Comment: The link you provided (to .py file) has working example for loading test data and calculating results. However, you cannot use a trained model "out of the box" because you need to know which part of the data it was trained on. This is why line :32 splits dataset into train and test chunks

Comment: hm I unnderstand but how can I input a sentence and get sentiment of it?

Comment: it is actually quite complex, as you are using keras preprocessed data for training so you have to preprocess your own in the same way, thus at this point it is impossible to reconstruct the process, as it is **data dependent**. Thus without actual train/test split you will not be able to reconstruct the preprocessing technique.

Answer (score 1):

**First**, split your dataset to `test`, `valid` and `train` and do some preprocessing:

```
from tensorflow import keras

print('load data')
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.imdb.load_data(num_words=10000)
word_index = keras.datasets.imdb.get_word_index()

print('preprocessing...')
x_train = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(x_train, maxlen=256)
x_test = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(x_test, maxlen=256)

x_val = x_train[:10000]
y_val = y_train[:10000]

x_train = x_train[10000:]
y_train = y_train[10000:]
```

As you see we also load `word_index` because we need it later to convert our sentence to the sequence of integers.

**Second**, define your model:

```
print('build model')
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Embedding(10000, 16))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(100))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

print('train model')
model.fit(x_train,
          y_train,
          epochs=5,
          batch_size=512,
          validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
          verbose=1)
```

**Finally**, `save` and `load` your model with:

```
print('save trained model...')
model.save('sentiment_keras.h5')
del model

print('load model...')
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('sentiment_keras.h5')
```

You can evaluate your model with `test-set`:

```
print('evaluation')
evaluation = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=512)
print('Loss:', evaluation[0], 'Accuracy:', evaluation[1])
```

If you want to **test the model on completely new sentence** you can do:

```
sample = 'this is new sentence and this very bad bad sentence'
sample_label = 0
# convert input sentence to tokens based on word_index
inps = [word_index[word] for word in sample.split() if word in word_index]
# the sentence length should be the same as the input sentences
inps = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences([inps], maxlen=256)
print('Accuracy:', model.evaluate(inps, [sample_label], batch_size=1)[1])
print('Sentiment score: {}'.format(model.predict(inps)[0][0]))
```